# Problem while creating a wrapper service for PrimeNG MessageService (Angular 8)

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, angular-services

I have created a wrapper service for MessageService from PrimeNG instead of calling `add()` method directly in the app but it is not working neither throwing any compiletime/runtime error. The code is getting executed verified by debugger. It works when i call use MessageService directly.

Is there anything like the MessageService has to be injected in comonent to be able to interact with its html tag which is placed in `app.component.html`?

Please refer to wrapper service code below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ToastService {

  constructor(public messageService: MessageService) { }

  success(message: string) {
    this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', detail: message });
  }

  error(message: string) {
    this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', detail: message });
  }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: NotABot, did you figure it out? This is exactly what I'm trying to do, with the same problem.

Comment: @BenNieting, Unfortunately no. Please post if you find anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DId you tried using NgZone

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private ngZone: NgZone)
this.ngZone.run(() => {
      success(message: string) {
       this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', detail: message });
    }
});
```

Comment: Nope, not working. I wonder why using NgZone would make any difference in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `<p-toast position="top-right"></p-toast>` in component template?
or in the root-level to the app.component.html?
option2: you can use `<p-messages [(value)]="msgs"></p-messages>` where msgs is defined in component like `msgs: Message[] = [];`
it seems like your wrapper is ok and you just need to add it to template